# simple regex [a-z] work for letter but fails on Word

Tags: java, regex, nuxeo

I am writing a simple regex validator method in nuxeo java

```
mystring.matches("[a-z]")
```

This validate correctly if enter any letter .  a or b  or z .

This validation allows to enter a letter but when i enter a word it fails.

Why is that ? Do i have to enter any length param ?

Comment: The javadoc of `String#matches(..)` has your answer.

Comment: Do you intend to see if the input string contains a single letter, or do you intend to see if _all_ the input string is composed of letters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only allow a single match of a character. "[a-z]+" would let 1 to N characters of lowercase to pass.

Answer (score 2):

`[a-z]` means match one character in the range a-z. If you want to match an arbitrary number of characters, 0 or more, you can use `[a-z]*`. If you want to match one character or more, `[a-z]+`, or if you want to be more specific, `[a-z]{4}` matches only 4 characters while `[a-z]{4,6}` matches 4, 5, or 6 characters.

See [this article on repetition quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) for more information.